# How to fix mysql full-text index is too slow

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I moved from the local environment to the `rds` environment of aws.

```sql
innodb_ft_enable_stopword=0
ngram_token_size=1
```

I have the above two settings.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `keywordTable` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `createdAt` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `updatedAt` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `userId` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `keyword` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_2dd7820158cdf3dsasf` (`userId`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `IDX_e89f81c42dswdfdf` (`keyword`) /*!50100 WITH PARSER `ngram` */ ,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_2dd7820158c24303eb9f6618b9f` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=947181 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

The table was created with the query above.

```sql
SELECT keyword from keywordTable where MATCH(keyword) AGAINST('+aa' in boolean mode);
```

The query above takes almost a minute. Even the explain takes more than 4 seconds, and the result is as follows.

| left | center | right |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | Three |

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | keywordTable |  | fulltext | IDX_e89f81c42dswdfdf | IDX_e89f81c42dswdfdf | 0 | const | 1 | 100.00 | Using where; Ft_hints: no_ranking |

And I also tried `optimize table keyword Table` and `REPAIR TABLE keyword Table QUICK` but same result. what more do i have to do?

Comment: How big is the table?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How  many rows were returned by the query?

Comment: `ngram_token_size=1` seems low.  Why did you use that value?

Comment: @RickJames about 460000 data, and the pool size is 268435456!

Comment: @RickJames I use that table for searching. This is to make it possible to search even for one character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching for a single character...

```
SELECT keyword from keywordTable WHERE keyword LIKE '%a%';
```

is probably the fastest.  It will have to scan the entire table, and cannot use any type of index.

Doing the equivalent with "ngram" is *probably* slower -- it must scan a chunk of the index, then reach (randomly) into the data to get the actual `keyword`.

Consider `ngram_token_size=2` (and rebuild the index) and either do the LIKE above (for 1-char search) or do the FULLTEXT that you have (for 2+).

Then compare that (ngram=2) with the equivalent LIKE:

```
SELECT keyword from keywordTable WHERE keyword LIKE '%aa%';
```

It may be that you should not use ngram for "2" either.

Comment: Thank you for answer! Are you saying to set ngram_size =2, match against from 3 characters, and use like search for 2 characters or less?

Comment: Hmmm...  Try both.

Comment: I'll test it with your answer!

Comment: Excuse me, can I ask another question? If 4 letters are searched and the searchWord is 'AB CDE', I try to search with '+AB +BCDE', but in that case, if ngram size is 3, +AB search is ignored. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: @KunAguero - What kind of "words" are these?  If they are "part numbers", it is real messy to conjure up anything efficient.  Perhaps turn all punctuation that would cause a word boundary into underscore?  (If underscore is not a "letter', pick "Q" or something else.)  It may need a double test, first with (fast) ngram, then with (slow) LIKE.

Comment: I want to search for music. If the name of the singer 'iu' is smaller than the minimum token size, it will not be indexed. So, if a user searches for 'iu', it's fine, but if a user searches for 'iu - good day', iu is excluded and only good day results are returned.

Comment: @KunAguero - `... AGAINST('iu +good +day' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ...` -- note the lack of a `+` before the short word.